# Putting breadcrumbs in the toilet

Tags: halacha, bathroom, bread, segulah

Mishnah Berurah writes in [180:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.180.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that while throwing crumbs onto the ground where they will be stepped on is kasha l'aninus, God forbid, this does not apply when the crumbs are thrown into water. According to an important rabbi I asked, the latter exemption also includes flushing them down the toilet.  However, if someone put the crumbs in the toilet without flushing them, but waiting until he defecated or urinated in the toilet before flushing it, would this constitute disrespect to the crumbs that would be kasha l'aninus God forbid?

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Simmons

Comment: If a local rav can't answer, you may want to post this question on www.dinonline.com. They have a team of rabbanim who are quite good at analyzing these issues. It may take a few days to get an answer, but, they answer just about every question.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but, it seems to have dropped out of attention. You may want to place a bounty on it. I would, myself, but, it's not a highly "motivating" question for me to do it.